# Using dedicated GPU on laptop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, opengl

I have laptop with dedicated NVidia GPU and integrated Intel GPU. Can I force specific program (or - in worst case - the whole system and all programs) to use dedicated unit instead of integrated one, preferably using Nvidia drivers?

System version: Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Yes, [through the nvidia control panel](http://i.imgur.com/3ef7Aoh.png).

Comment: Well, then the question is how can this be achieved.

Comment: I added a link to an image of the option in the panel to the comment above (sorry it took sometime to upload it :) ).

Comment: And what in case if there is no "PRIME Profiles" tab? All I can see on my laptop is "Application Profiles" and "nvidia-settings Configuration".

Comment: How did you install the driver? Because the Nvidia drivers tested in Ubuntu (the ones from the repositories) should automatically install PRIME when they get installed.

Comment: Just reinstalled it using Software & Updates and now I have the Prime Profiles tab - tested it with my application and everything seems to work, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install the drivers from the Ubuntu repositories through the dedicated interface, PRIME should be installed automatically, and you will find the relative option in the Nvidia Settings interface:

[image: Nvidia PRIME interface]